# Hide MasterViewcontroller when tab is selected iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have an app having four tabs. Now  MasterVC is displayed on the left when it's in landscape. 
But my aim is that in landscape , it should show MasterVC ONLY when it's in TAB1. For TAB2-TAB4 , the masterVC should not be displayed. I am not using any button or popover here.

How to accomplish this..

Please guide/help.

Comment: How is your hierarchy set up? Is your tab bar controller inside the detail view of one single split view controller, or is there a separate split view controller inside each tab of the tab bar controller?

Comment: If you are not displaying the split view at once and are only using master and detailed view separately. Why do u need a splitview controller? You can play around better without the split view controller..

Comment: @AmyWorrall I have only one SplitVC and that is the starting controller and you are right, tab bar VC inside the DetailVC.

Comment: @SharanyaKM I have to displayed both Detail & Master VC at the same time only for TAB1. in landscape. Not for others.

Comment: any suggestion guys? it's getting very urgent to me.. any idea will be very help ful to me...